# How to redirect trace output to a file

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am tracing a prolog program

```
1 ?- trace.
true.

[trace] 1 ?- solve.
   Call: (7) solve ?
```

I also tried

```
tell('trace_op.txt').
```

the file is created but empty

Now the trace is really many lines . I want to redirect the output to a file
Can we redirect it to a file ?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 8

Answer (score 7):

On Windows using SWI-Prolog you can use [protocol/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=protocol/1)

[protocol/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=protocol/1) will copy the output that goes to the screen to a file. So if you run a [trace/0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=trace/0) and the output goes to the screen, a copy will be sent to a file. To simplify having to write the entire path for protocol/1 I find it easier to set the current working directory using [working_directory/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=working_directory/2) and then only set the specific file with protocol/1.

### Example

For this example create a file, e.g.

> trace_example.pl

and add some facts and predicates to demonstrate tracing.

```
parent(ann,helen).
parent(helen,henry).
parent(henry,mary).

ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Z),
    ancestor(Z,Y).
```

Open SWI-Prolog top level and use [consult/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=consult/1) to load the file

```
consult("C:/ ... /trace_example.pl").
```

N.B. The directory separators are / not \. Change them if necessary.

Since the SWI-Prolog terminal on Windows will default to using color with tracing and that will add unneeded escape sequences to the output file [set_prolog_flag/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=set_prolog_flag/2) needs to be run to turn the color off.

```
?- set_prolog_flag(color_term,false).
true.
```

Verify that the terminal is not using color.

```
?- current_prolog_flag(color_term,X).
X = false.
```

A quick run to verify the predicate and facts work

```
?- ancestor(ann,henry).
true ;
false.
```

Now set the current working directory to where the output file will be created.

```
?- working_directory(_,"C:/Users/Eric/Documents/Prolog").
```

and verify that the change occurred

```
?- working_directory(CWD,CWD).
CWD = 'c:/users/eric/documents/prolog/'.
```

Since I don't want to press the space bar for each trace output I disable user interaction for all the debug ports using [leash/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=leash/1)

```
?- leash(-all).
```

and since I want to see all of the output from all of the debug ports I enable them all with [visible/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=visible/1)

```
?- visible(+all).
```

Enable the copying of the screen to a file

```
?- protocol("./trace_output.txt").
```

start the tracer

```
?- trace.
```

and run a query to be traced

```
?- ancestor(ann,henry).

   Call: (8) ancestor(ann, henry) ? creep
   Call: (9) parent(ann, henry) ? creep
   Fail: (9) parent(ann, henry) ? creep
   Redo: (8) ancestor(ann, henry) ? creep
   Call: (9) parent(ann, _1124) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent(ann, helen) ? creep
   Call: (9) ancestor(helen, henry) ? creep
   Call: (10) parent(helen, henry) ? creep
   Exit: (10) parent(helen, henry) ? creep
   Exit: (9) ancestor(helen, henry) ? creep
   Exit: (8) ancestor(ann, henry) ? creep
true ;
   Redo: (9) ancestor(helen, henry) ? creep
   Call: (10) parent(helen, _1124) ? creep
   Exit: (10) parent(helen, henry) ? creep
   Call: (10) ancestor(henry, henry) ? creep
   Call: (11) parent(henry, henry) ? creep
   Fail: (11) parent(henry, henry) ? creep
   Redo: (10) ancestor(henry, henry) ? creep
   Call: (11) parent(henry, _1124) ? creep
   Exit: (11) parent(henry, mary) ? creep
   Call: (11) ancestor(mary, henry) ? creep
   Call: (12) parent(mary, henry) ? creep
   Fail: (12) parent(mary, henry) ? creep
   Redo: (11) ancestor(mary, henry) ? creep
   Call: (12) parent(mary, _1124) ? creep
   Fail: (12) parent(mary, _1124) ? creep
   Fail: (11) ancestor(mary, henry) ? creep
   Fail: (10) ancestor(henry, henry) ? creep
   Fail: (9) ancestor(helen, henry) ? creep
   Fail: (8) ancestor(ann, henry) ? creep
false.
```

end the tracing

```
?- nodebug.
```

and end the copying of the screen to the file

```
?- noprotocol.
```

Now open the file `C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Prolog\trace_output.txt`

```
true.  
  
10 ?- trace.  
  
  
true.  
  
[trace] 10 ?- ancestor(ann,henry).  
  
  
   Call: (8) ancestor(ann, henry)  
   Unify: (8) ancestor(ann, henry)  
   Call: (9) parent(ann, henry)  
   Fail: (9) parent(ann, henry)  
   Redo: (8) ancestor(ann, henry)  
   Unify: (8) ancestor(ann, henry)  
   Call: (9) parent(ann, _6466)  
   Unify: (9) parent(ann, helen)  
   Exit: (9) parent(ann, helen)  
   Call: (9) ancestor(helen, henry)  
   Unify: (9) ancestor(helen, henry)  
   Call: (10) parent(helen, henry)  
   Unify: (10) parent(helen, henry)  
   Exit: (10) parent(helen, henry)  
   Exit: (9) ancestor(helen, henry)  
   Exit: (8) ancestor(ann, henry)  
true  ;  
   Redo: (9) ancestor(helen, henry)  
   Unify: (9) ancestor(helen, henry)  
   Call: (10) parent(helen, _6466)  
   Unify: (10) parent(helen, henry)  
   Exit: (10) parent(helen, henry)  
   Call: (10) ancestor(henry, henry)  
   Unify: (10) ancestor(henry, henry)  
   Call: (11) parent(henry, henry)  
   Fail: (11) parent(henry, henry)  
   Redo: (10) ancestor(henry, henry)  
   Unify: (10) ancestor(henry, henry)  
   Call: (11) parent(henry, _6466)  
   Unify: (11) parent(henry, mary)  
   Exit: (11) parent(henry, mary)  
   Call: (11) ancestor(mary, henry)  
   Unify: (11) ancestor(mary, henry)  
   Call: (12) parent(mary, henry)  
   Fail: (12) parent(mary, henry)  
   Redo: (11) ancestor(mary, henry)  
   Unify: (11) ancestor(mary, henry)  
   Call: (12) parent(mary, _6466)  
   Fail: (12) parent(mary, _6466)  
   Fail: (11) ancestor(mary, henry)  
   Fail: (10) ancestor(henry, henry)  
   Fail: (9) ancestor(helen, henry)  
   Fail: (8) ancestor(ann, henry)  
false.  
  
[trace] 11 ?-  nodebug.  
  
  
true.  
  
12 ?- noprotocol.
```

Comment: The ANSI control sequences now have some color. Is this what you want?

Comment: `-all` is blue and `+all` is black. Does this improve readability?

Answer (score 2):

### Linux

If you're using Linux, you can use the `tee` command:

```
$ swipl 2>&1 | tee swipl.log
...
1 ?- trace.
true.

[trace] 1 ?- solve.
   Call: (7) solve ? 
...
```

The `tee` command sends all of its standard input to the standard output and to to the specified file in parallel. The `2>&1` ensures that you also capture any standard error in the standard output as well so it would appear in the `swipl.log` file.

### Windows

In Windows, if you use `PowerShell`, you can use the `Tee-Object` command which works similarly:

```
swipl-win | Tee-Object -file swipl.log
```

I'm assuming here that `swipl-win` is what the command line program for SWI Prolog in Windows, and that it exists in your program path for `PowerShell`.

When you exit `swipl`, then you can see all of what happened in `swipl.log`.

Comment: I am using Windows 8

Comment: PS C:\> swipl | Tee-Object -file swipl.log
swipl : The term 'swipl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ swipl | Tee-Object -file swipl.log
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (swipl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @Star123, sorry, `swipl` is what the SWI Prolog command is called in Linux. I just edited my answer again as I looked it up in the manual and the command in Windows is `swipl-win.exe` (I believe). You'll need to substitute what it is in Windows and make sure it's in a path so that the PowerShell can find it. That's what the error message is telling you.